# Moderator elections

Tags: support, moderation

Where can I find information about moderator elections, i.e. when was the last one, what was the outcome, and when will be the next one, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Travel.SE is currently in public beta, and as such, does not have elections. We did have [community nominations held here on meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/108), and then based on those suggestions [StackExchange chose pro-tem moderators](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/108). Pro-tem moderators do not have a fixed term, as far as I know, with the basic idea being they remain in the position a) as long as the site is in public beta b) they can opt out any time they want, say, due to time constraints or personal reasons.

Since [Travel.SE is graduating soon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/823/108), this means that we'll have community elections too around the same time.